# Greyed #else directive block in C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, preprocessor

In the code below, the block of code between #else and #endif is **greyed** out as a multi-line comment.
[Image Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpWS2.png)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    newImgAimX = Mouse.current.position.value.x;
    newImgAimY = Mouse.current.position.value.y;
#else
    newImgAimX = imgAim.transform.position.x + v2MouseDelta.x;
    newImgAimY = imgAim.transform.position.y + v2MouseDelta.y;
#endif
```

Is it possible to make syntax highlighting work in this block?

Comment: My typical workaround is to temporarily invert the #if condition while I'm editing that section.

Comment: I think this is a bug. This block of code should not look like a comment!

Comment: It's a preprocess directive and means that grayed code will not get compiled because `UNITY_EDITOR` is equal to `false` value.

Comment: @RezaNoei: actually a `#if` tests if the symbol (in this case `UNITY_EDITOR`) is defined or not, not what it's value is (it's a compile time symbol). The behavior is like that of `#ifdef` in C or C++

Comment: Another possible workaround is to temporarily put `#undef UNITY_EDITOR` before these lines of code. It seems you should be able to select a different environment with the [build settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html#:~:text=Testing%20precompiled%20code), but I'm not an expert on Unity.

Comment: It seems impossible. It's not really a comment, but a preprocessor directive. They are not part of the executing code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

That's a compile time constant or a preprocessor directive. That means the correct condition can be determined at compile time by the compiler. It is greyed out for that reason. It is showing you which block of code is going to be compiled. To fix that problem, convert each block into a function.

For example:

```
// ref is used to indicated that the object will be mutated 
public void CompileForX(ref MyObj obj) {
     
}
public void CompileForY(ref MyObj obj) {

}
```

And then:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    CompileForX(obj);
#else
    CompileForY(obj);
#endif
```

However, this approach has a drawback. It is very important to mention that both functions `CompileForX` and `CompileForY` will be actually compiled and they will become part of the assembly. This is while what goes in the conditional block is only and only compiled if the condition is true at compile time.

Comment: I could come up with this type of option myself. I thought there was a setting in MSVC that changes this strange behavior of the interpreter. But if it doesn't, then I'll have to temporarily invert the #if condition to edit the #else block as suggested by Joe Sewell.

Comment: @Giorgio.K I personally don't use an IDE as I don't like the code completion features IDEs provide, so I have never faced this issue. But since you are using an IDE, this is an expected behavior. Because, the IDE is actually showing you which block of the code will be compiled.